# Stemming in Wordnet API

Tags: wordnet, stemming

I'm using the MIT Wordnet API (http://projects.csail.mit.edu/jwi/) to use wordnet in my Java application. I'm having the following problem:

If I search "signed" in the Wordnet Search at http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu, I get "signed" as an adjective (e.g. signed book) and "sign" as a verb. Perfect.

However when I use the MIT API, I only get the adjective. I understand that this is due to stemming, so I use the wordnet stemmer available in the MIT API and get "sign". Good. However "sign" could also be a noun now... and things could get quite complicated.

Is there an "easy" way I could get the same results as Wordnet Search web interface via the API? I don't mind if I use another API.

Thanks!

Krt_Malta

Answer (score 0):

I use [JAWS](http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws/index.html) ,  that works fine for Wordnet by Princeton University and is a very simple API to use.

Comment: And if u want a good stemmer you can use the snowball stemmer which is available at a number of sources

Answer (score 0):

Use parts of speech tagger using

```
 import pos_tagger
```

Comment: Perhaps you could include rather more code or an overview to indicate what to do with this?